# How to Display and Update a Message or Label containg results using TopLevel Tkinter inside a for loop at every iteration in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel

I am building a GUI Python code using tkinter. I have a CSTR model that is solved inside a for loop; the values are updated inside the for loop. I have four parameters that are being updated T,Ca,Tc,q. I am using the TopLevel() to display the results in EVERY iteration inside for loop. In other words, I want the results at each iteration to be shown once the results are out on a display, and once I am in another interation, I want to open a new window file again and update the values with the new calculated values in the for loop. I have used the destroy function using the same time of the iterations in the for loop.

Kindly find my code attached below ( I have attached part of the code only for simplicity):

```
 # Time Interval (min)
t = np.linspace(0,800,401) # every 2 seconds
duration=8000 # I also tried 2000,4000,6000,1000,etc.

    # Simulate CSTR
    for i in range(len(t)-1):
        # simulate one time period (0.02 sec each loop)
        ts = [t[i],t[i+1]]
        #read CSTR Process T and Ca (to be controlled)

        y = odeint(cstr,x0,ts,args=(u[i],u2[i],Tf,Caf))
        # retrieve measurements
        Ca[i+1] = y[-1][0]
        T[i+1] = y[-1][1]
        # insert measurement
        m.T.MEAS = T[i+1]
        m.Ca.MEAS=Ca[i+1]

        #run MPC controller

        # solve MPC
        m.solve(disp=True)

        # retrieve new Tc and q values

        u[i+1] = m.Tc.NEWVAL
        u2[i+1]=m.q.NEWVAL

        #run optimization

        x=optimizer(numa,numb,numc,numd,Tsp[i+1],Casp[i+1],u[i+1],u2[i+1],numi,numj,nume,numf,numg,numh,numk,numl) # or put T and Ca (not sp)


        #updating the setpoints of the controller from the optimizer

        #Set the setpoint temperature equal to the optimized Temperature

        Tsp[i+1]=x[1]

        m.T.SPHI = Tsp[i+1] + DT
        m.T.SPLO = Tsp[i+1] - DT

        #Set the setpoint conc. equal to the optimized conc.
        Casp[i+1]=x[4]

        m.Ca.SPHI = Casp[i+1] + DT
        m.Ca.SPLO = Casp[i+1] - DT

        # retrieve new Tc and q values

        #update Tc and q values from optimizer as targets


        f[i]=m.Tc.NEWVAL #MPC
        f2[i]=x[2] #Optimizer (target)

        z[i]=m.q.NEWVAL #MPC
        z2[i]=x[3] #Optimizer (target)



        x2=optimize(f[i],f2[i],nume,numf)# MINIMIZES THE ERROR DIFFERENCE BETWEEN MPC AND OPTIMIZER Tc value
        x3=optimize2(z[i],z2[i],numg,numh)# MINIMIZES THE ERROR DIFFERENCE BETWEEN MPC AND OPTIMIZER q value

        #updating the Tc and q MV values

        u[i+1] = x2
        u2[i+1]=x3

        # update initial conditions
        x0[0] = Ca[i+1]
        x0[1] = T[i+1]
        #to show the results on GUI

        top1=Toplevel()

        output1=" q optimum= %d m^3/s \n"%(z[i]) #takes the output q of MPC
        output1+="q target= %d m^3/s \n"%(z2[i])#takes the output of the optimizer
        output1+="Tc optimum= %d K \n"%(f[i])#takes the output Tc of MPC
        output1+="Tc target= %d K \n"%(f2[i])#takes the output of the optimizer
        top1.title('Manipulated Variables')

        Message(top1,text=output1,padx=30,pady=30).pack()
        top1.after(duration,top1.destroy)
```

What is actually happening is that the window is only opening once all the runs of the for loops are done (take a huge time) and not at every iteration/calculation in the for loop! How can I display the window inside the for loop at every iteration and NOT once all the loop is done? Is there some sort of function or something where I can manually force the window to be displayed? For instance, I was able to shows plots using plt module that are updated in every iteration inside the for loop, I want to do exactly the same using toplevel() .

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a GUI, your code is basically a *guest* in the GUI toolkit's event loop (`mainloop` in tkinter).

So you cannot have a long-running loop in a GUI program; you have to structure your code differently. For example, say that you have a loop like this;

```
# *Long* list of data
data = [ ... ]
# storage for results
result = []
for item in data:
    rv = process(item)
    result.append(rv)
```

If you were to run such a loop in a GUI program, it would interrupt the flow of events. In effect it would freeze the GUI and render is unresponsive.

So in a tkinter GUI, you would have to do the calculations in a timeout handler. Below a sketch of the principle of dividing up a long-running job into small pieces that can be handled inside the GUI's event-loop.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# *Long* list of data
data = [ ... ]
# storage for results
result = []
index = 0

def iteration():
    '''Handles one iteration in the event loop.'''
    rv = process(data[index])
    result.append(rv)
    index += 1
    if index < len(data):
        root.after(100, iteration)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo('Calculations', 'Finished!')


def create_UI():
    # Create and place the widgets here.
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk(None)
    widgets = create_UI(root)
    root.after(100, iteration)
    root.mainloop()
```

As you can see, your code has to be structured differently in this case.

Note that on CPython only *one* thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode, so using threads is not really a good solution for this. Especially since a lot of GUI toolkits are not thread-safe, so you should *only* call GUI functions from one thread.

Another solution would be to run the calculation in a different program. That program could then communicate with the GUI using a `Queue`. You would have to use a a timeout function in the GUI to monitor the Queue at regular intervals and display the results. This is not a simpler solution, but might offer higher perfomance it you can divide the calculations up over several processes.

**Edit**:

Note that in the first solution, each iteration should only take a relateively small amount of time, say e.g. 100 ms. If it would take much longer, the GUI would feel unresponsive. If it is unfeasible to to that, then use the second solution (a separate program).

I don't really have a handy reference for this problem. But a simple pattern goes like this;

You write *two* programs.

The first program is a simple Python script that does its calculations in a regular for-loop. The only special thing is that *at the end of each iteration, it writes the values of T, Ca, Tc and q to a file.*

The second program is a Python tkinter program that uses the `after` method to inspect the modification time of the aforementioned file. If it detects that the file has changed, it reads the file and updates its display.

This approach completely *decouples* the problems of doing the calculations and displaying the intermediate results, meaning you can write and test them separately.

A general name for this solution is called a "file watcher", I think. This solution is so common I can't recall where I say it first.

Comment: Dear Roland, do you have a website/paper/reference that can help me achieve my goal (for the first approach)? In addition to that and for the second solution, what "different" program do you suggest to use in order to achieve this?

Comment: thank you for the support. I was attempting the second approach suggested by you. I saved the data I need to be shown in my initial posted code in order to save 3 different .csv files to be used in the other "after method" python code that displays the tkinter results. All of the csv files are in the column format and two of them have 6 rows and the 3rd only has 1 row (1 element). I want to show the three of these csv files on the other python script that applies the after method. the three csv files are being correctly updated at every iteration alone.

Comment: The csv files only have numbers, I also want to add some letters. and words to explain to the user. For instance, I want to type: Tc optimal = 283.42, q MPC= 20.41 ; I don't only want to take the numbers from the csv files.. In addition to that, how can I show each csv as a separate column on the window that pops up? I want to show every csv file on a separate column on the window with some explanation (words).

Comment: @MohamadIbrahim You comments are three to four different questions in themselves. :-) I would urge you to *keep it simple*. Write all the information formatted in the way you like it as one line to a text file. The GUI program then only has to read that line one line of one file, and set the contents of a label to the text it has just read.

Comment: do you think using PyQT instead of tkinter would be better in my case ?

Comment: @MohamadIbrahim GUI toolkits tend to work in a similar way. Most of the common ones follow the event-driven model. For this application I don't think it will make much of a difference.

Comment: can you please check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835093/destroy-function-not-destroying-a-frame-efficiently-after-the-first-iteration-in/60848523#60848523